# Malloc at the same heap location?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I am trying to understand what's behind the curtain with `malloc` and `free`. So I tried to reserve a pointer, affect a value, free it and get the same address using another `malloc` call.

I am expecting to get the same value as previously written at this particular location, but it is somehow different...

```
int main(void)
{
    int* foo;
    int* bar = malloc(sizeof *bar);
    *bar = 42;
    printf("&bar = %p, bar = %d\n", (void*)bar, *bar);
    free(bar);

    foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
    printf("&foo = %p, foo= %d\n", (void*)foo, *foo);

    return 0;
}
```

What I get is:

```
&bar = 0x800103a8, bar = 42
&foo = 0x800103a8, foo= 1630223800
```

Why is the read value different than `42`? Is it because of the `MMU`?

Comment: The contents of the memory given to you by `malloc` is *indeterminate*. Using it without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*. Just don't look at the memory until you initialized it, or you might catch [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: Also, on modern systems with virtual memory, a *virtual address* (as returned by `malloc`) doesn't have to match a *physical address* (actual RAM memory). A virtual address might not even point to RAM if the system has swapping, or file mapping.

Comment: So the answer is because of the `MMU` and my example will work on systems without `MMU`

Comment: "I am expecting to get the same value" on what grounds? "So the answer is because of the MMU" nope. "and my example will work on systems without MMU" nope.

Comment: In case of no `MMU`, it depends on malloc implementation. Multitasking/Multithreading can also affect your code, not with a single main obviously.

Comment: Systems like Linux implements "over-commit", basically "memory is not really allocated until you try to access it". Basically systems like this return a faulty virtual address that maps to no physical memory on a call to `malloc`. Then when the faulty address is accessed, the processor generates a MMU exception, then the system catches it as an event and allocate physical memory and map that virtual address to it. So even though they are identical virtual addresses, they are mapped to different physical addresses, so deferences to different values

Comment: "I am expecting to get the same value" you shouldn't and if you want to, don't use malloc/free instead implement a well defined sharing mechanism for your values.

Comment: _So the answer is because of the MMU and my example will work on systems without MMU_. No, that's not the answer. The answer is : **the content of memory obtained by `malloc` is indeterminate. Period.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is

1. implementation defined, the C standard does not impose any restrictions on what allocator strategies are used in `malloc`. `BSD`, for example, uses [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/), while glibc might use a different allocator.
2. possibly undefined behaviour. As already mentioned by [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg), the value of the memory returned by `malloc` is indeterminate, and accessing it might be undefined.

Comment: It is not necessarily undefined behavior though, it depends on the implementation. If the indeterminate value isn't a trap representation, then accessing it merely gives you an unspecified garbage value.

Comment: @Lundin True. The C standard, however, only defines `char` to not hold any trap representations.

Comment: It is **not** implementzation defined. Reading from indeterminate objects is UB.

Comment: @Olaf Sigh, no, reading an **indeterminate** value is not necessarily undefined. The C standard states, it's only undefined if the value is able to hold a trap representation, it also further states, that `char` can not have any trap representation. Not mentioning, that most modern machines are 2s complement, and, as we all know, 2s complement integers do not have any trap representations.

Comment: @Leandros: Sorry, you are right about the read. Still it is not implementation defined. That would require an implementation to specify its behaviour. Re trap-representation: that just requires a free code, which is very well possible with 2s complement, too, e.g. `(int32_t)0x80000000`.

Comment: @Olaf How is `0x80000000` a trap representation? It's simply `INT_MIN` on any system where `int` is 32-bit.

Comment: @Leandros: I did not say it **is**. Just it **could be**! It already is larger than the max. value required for `INT_MIN`. But even for 16 bit (the min. bitwidth an `int` can have), this is possible. max. value for `INT_MIN` is `-32767`. Which would leave `-32768` available as trap-representation. That would not break compliant code. Similar for `long` and `long long`.

Comment: @Olaf It is implementation-defined if a system has trap representations for the given type. If you read an indeterminate value which results in a trap representation, the behavior is undefined, otherwise not. On mainstream two's complement computers, it is unlikely that you would encounter trap representations for most types.

Comment: Overall, designing for compatibility with exotic nonsense systems isn't meaningful, the C standard be damned. If someone decides to compile my code on some garage-made, hand-bonded DSP from the 80s, I hope I'm causing them as many mysterious bugs as possible.

Comment: @Lundin: The first sentence still stands, as there is no requirement for an implementation to define how memory is allocated. The other aspect are trap-representations which are ID, of course. My last comment were about leandros' claim 2s complement cannot have a trap-representation. About the compatibility: If you want 2s complement guaranteed, use `int32_t` etc. Making overflow UB actually allows for wider optimisations, including saturated arithmetics for a specific implementation (and that is not necessarily an "exotic" feature).

Comment: ... This would still be UB by the standard, but an implementation can guarantee a specific behaviour, e.g. gcc `-fwrapv`.